# Retrieve ID after save with Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I am using the Parse javascript api .
So I am new to using parse. I have createda new class in the data browser and have information saving to it.

What I would like to do is do the save but get the id that Parse automatically creates. Is there a way after a save to return a column from the data?

```
var TestData = Parse.Object.extend("TestData");
        var myObj = new TestData();
        myObj.save({hs_user: frm_hs_user}, {
            success: function(response){
                alert("did it");
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert(error.message);   
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work

```
var query = new Parse.Query(TestData);
query.equalTo("objectId"); 
query.find({
    success: function (results) {
        alert(results)
    }
```

[Here is a better example of what i ment](http://jsbin.com/uvevax/1/edit)

EDIT: [Example with object.id](http://jsbin.com/ojuyoj/1/edit)

Comment: That partially answers it. Question is how do I get the id back. alerting the results simply gives me objects. is i do a tostring i get :native code"?

Comment: getting the objectId is a pain i keep forgetting how to do it, but ill look into it it will just take some time.

Comment: Yeah i would appreciate it! I see what you are doing in the example but that just gets me everything in the class. Once I save it would be nice to find out what the id was of that save so I can pull it back into my app and look things up with it later.

Comment: myObj.id should give you the object id

Comment: are you serious? It was that easy just alerting the id in the success. Sometimes I feel dumb. Put up a answer so you get credit.

Comment: wow I didn't know it was that easy lol. I did the same thing in one of my projects in such a convoluted way this would have saved me a lot of time lol.

Comment: To clarify for anyone else looking for this: in the success function in the answer - call results.id and that's the ID. See it in action in the second example that is linked in the answer. Thanks guys!