# how to get most recently added parse.com object

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Is there any way to do a query in Parse to get the most recently added PFObject type?

I know that I can do a query with a greater than criteria, but it would be very useful if there was a function to get the most recent object added when no date is known.

Comment: This is for the JavaScript API but it might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091210/retrieve-id-after-save-with-parse/17091498#17091498

Comment: assuming RestApi within one Class type, adding 2 conditions to query will return last object created within that class:  --data-urlencode 'order=-createdAt'
--data-urlencode 'limit=1"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just add a descending order on `createdAt` and get the first object:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClassName"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    // code
}];
```

In Swift:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "YourClassName")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {(object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // code
}
```

Comment: In Swift: 
var query = PFQuery(className:"YourClassName")
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil || object == nil {
    print("The getFirstObject request failed.")
  } else {
    // The find succeeded.
    print("Successfully retrieved the object.")
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

This may not address the use case in question. I often want to get back the objectId of the object i just added in code. While it might be automatically possible, i have missed any info in this regard. So i usually have my own unique identifier that i add, and then retrieve the object by that identifier in the async block.. thus getting the objectId..